# Is the pop-up on text-selection editable in recent MS-Word (2013... 2019...)?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Are there some settings or tweaks to edit the options that pop-up when selecting text in Word?

[image]

I would like to be able to add there *Copy* and *Cut*, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, but the right-click Text Context menu contains both commands already and can be edited.

[image: Screenshot of right-click Text Context Menu]

If you want to edit *that menu*, you can find directions on [Greg Maxey's page on Customizing the Text Shortcut menu](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_shortcut_menu.html).

Comment: I knew about right-click context of course :) but never tried to edit that. I have asked because the selection pop-up is a more recent feature that *might* have included some less-known tweaks. But it doesn't, so "no" is the answer.